# How can god help us if he is opposite to material world?

Tags: gods

Spiritual world and material world both are opposites.

Spirituality says to leave love on materialistic things.

In material world, you need money, gold etc related to materials.

Then how can I worship god to give me this or give me that in material world.

How can god fulfill my desire to have something if god want me to do not show love on materials as nothing is permanent.

While saying to get out of materialistic things, why he created the gods and goddesses which helps in getting material items which will not come after death also

Comment: The idea is to eventually transcend material desires. Slowly you will become more and more detached of materialism when you become more religious.

Comment: God - Brahman, does not help with material objects. Help for material objects is done by praying to the devis and devas. Be careful what you wish for because you will get it - and the karma.